# How do I flow text to the next page in oracle reports?

Tags: oraclereports

I am using Oracle Report Builder 10.1.2.0.2.

I have users of an application who enter a narrative that can be up to 10,000 characters (from a database CLOB). That information must be presented on a formal form, the layout of which is created by my report (as opposed to a pre-printed form).

How can I:

1. Repeat the entire page as many times as are needed for the text supplied but have each page maintain the proper form? Or...
2. In the alternative: Create the report with multiple pages with text automatically flowing to the proper place on the next page?

My predecessors have used logic in the database to split the test into pages. But that has the serious drawback of either wasted space or values being cut off, depending on the data. Doing it at the report level will, I hope, allow it to intelligently break pages based on the actual rendered text size.